# How to use Redux actions for multi-dimensional object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple action to set states in n1 dimension
My state object and reducer looks like this

```
    const F2F = {
        openF2F: false,
        ...
    }

    const initialState = {
        showModal: false,
        F2F,
        ...
    }

export default function reducer(state=initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case psActions.ON_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.fieldName]: action.value
            }

        default:
            return state
  }
}
```

I have a problem how to make an action to point to the state object

```
export function onChangeDim(value, name, dimension) {
    return {
        type:      psActions.ON_CHANGE,
        fieldName: dimension[name],//Tried many things her
        value:     value
    }
}
```

**Update**
Now I know how to point to the F2F object

```
case psActions.ON_CHANGE_DIM:
    return {
        ...state,
        [action.dimension]: {
            [action.fieldName]:action.value
        }
    }
```

But don't know how to pass rest of states inside F2F. Because now when I set one state it's only one inside
Can any one help me?

Comment: What does the `dimension` parameter look like for this case? What is being passed in to `onChangeDim`?

Comment: @dpaulus 'F2F' i need to point to the initialState.F2F.state

Comment: if `action.fieldName === "F2F"` then `action.value` will be the new `state.F2F`

Comment: @KyleRichardson yes you are right. have a look at my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below block to solve your nested state issue.

If you're using babel [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/), which it looks like you are.

```
return {
    ...state,
    [action.dimension]: {
        ...state[action.dimension],
        [action.fieldName]:action.value
    }
}
```

`Object.assign({}, state[action.dimensions], { ... })` could be used otherwise.

EDIT: To address your comment;

Please have a look at the documentation over at MDN about [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

So in this example: `Object.assign({}, state[action.dimensions], { ... })` we are taking an empty object `{}` and assigning all *enumerable* and *own* properties from `state[action.dimensions]` into it. Then we take the *enumerable* and *own* properties from `{ ... }` and apply them to the updated object.

**Merging objects with same properties**

> The properties are overwritten by other objects that have the same properties later in the parameters order

This is what the `...object` is being transformed into when you use the babel [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) plugin.

**Warning for Deep Clone**

> For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

Comment: Thats work! Can you explain more about `Object.assign(state[action.dimensions], { ... })` cannot make it work

Comment: Take a look at my edit, going to add some to it. `Object.assign({}, state[action.dimensions], { ... })` where { ... } are your new properties.

Comment: Is `Object.assign()` any way better than my method?

Comment: Not at all. Its just the way your method is doing it _under the hood_. It is what your code transpiles into. I actually use the babel plugin all the time, babel is awesome! I included it for completeness so that it would help other people with the same problem who are not using the babel plugin.